# Problems with fragment instantiation on ui thread

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragment, kotlin-coroutines, android-jetpack

This is more of a general question, since i am not sure i am missing something.

My setup is the following: Single activity app, using navigation components and launching a fragment with a [Stepper Layout by Stepstone](https://github.com/stepstone-tech/android-material-stepper).

This stepper contains four fragments, one of which is very heavy on the ui thread. Just to imagine it a bit, it has 2 map views, a lot of edittexts and other location-based stuff.

When i launch this stepper fragment, i get a noticeable amount of lag, with android stopping the nav animation and just opening the stepper immediately after its done. This, in my opinion is a really bad sign since on slower devices there might be a noticeable amount of lag when launching it.

My assumption is for now that this happens because of the one heavy fragment (if i fill the stepper with other fragments, theres no lag). I tried wrapping all of the initial logic of that fragment in `onViewCreated` into a  `viewLifecycleOwner.lifecycleScope.launch{...}` function, but to no avail.

So to summarize:

I sadly can't point to a single point of code that is causing this lag, but **what ways are there to reduce the ui thread load when instantiating a fragment**, or is it the fault of the UI thread at all?

My only idea right now is to replace this stepper completely and build my own based on navigation components, but this is only a last-try-solution since it would require the most effort.

Comment: What exactly is "location-based stuff". You should put any heavy work off the main thread. Maybe you can trace the problem, by only inflating your view without any other heavy computation, and vice versa. So you will know where the lag comes from.

Comment: @ChristianB initializing a fused location provider, but theoretically only when a button in that fragment is pressed so i doubt that what couses the heavy load on the main thread.  i assume it is most likely the two map views, and the textwatchers that cause the problem

Comment: If you are creating the view programmatically and if it takes a while, you could consider doing this off the main thread as well. Once it is done you could return the results back to the main thread to show it in your fragment.

Comment: Can't you move all the heavy load in a worker thread?

Comment: @Christianb is there a recommended way to do this with kotlin coroutines?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are creating the view programmatically and if it takes a while (because you need to create a lot of views), you could consider doing this off the main thread. Once it is done you could return the results back to the main thread and add it to your view hierarchy in your fragment.

You can do basic view initialization in `onCreateView()`.

```kotlin
override fun onCreateView(): View? {
  // create your basic view first
}
```

Then in `onViewCreated()` you could start computing the heavy view parts (with coroutines or any other threadind mechanism) like:

```kotlin
override fun onViewCreated(...) {
  lifecycleScope.launch(Dispatchers.Main) { 
    val complexView: View = heavyViewCreation() // result comes back on the main thread (Dispatchers.Main)
    // add complexView to your existing view hierachy
  }
}

suspend fun heavyViewCreation(): View = withContext(Dispatchers.Default) {
  // create your complex view here, computation is off the main thread (Dispatchers.Default)
}
```

**Dokumentation**

- [Use coroutines for main-safety](https://developer.android.com/kotlin/coroutines-adv#main-safety)

Comment: I thanked you for this answer because it answers my original question. However I just realized that my lag results from the initial fragment view instantiation, specifically one additional combination  of a mapview inside this fragment that will be overlaid if a button is clicked. I will investigate further why this map fragment hangs up the fragment initialization so much, and open a new question if i can find the issue.